# Webpack working locally but not on AWS Server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to deploy my application to an AWS EC2 instance. In my local environment i can bundle everything no problem when I run `webpack`. On my AWS server i cloned my repo, but when i run webpack i get 
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`.

I just checked and both my local and AWS server are running the same NPM (5.3.0) and Node (8.6.0) versions, as well as webpack versions (webpack -g).

I have .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"]
}
```

webpack.config.babel.js:

```
import path from 'path';
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';

const client = {
  entry: {
    js: './src/app-client.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'static', 'js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: 'cacheDirectory=.babel_cache',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
export default [client];
```

The error is occuring on the first line of the webpack.config.babel.js

```
/home/ec2-user/FB/webpack.config.babel.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import path from 'path';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Why would it work fine locally and not on AWS? Any ideas on how to fix? Thank you.

PS: My development machine is macOS and the server is Amazon linux

Answer (score 1):

Replace this with

```
import path from 'path';
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';
```

With This

```
var path    = require('path');
var nodeExternals  = require('webpack-node-externals');
```

And this

```
export default [client];
```

With this

```
module.exports = client;
```

Also make sure the Webpack version installed on your local machine is the same as that on your AWS server.

Also I think you are missing a preset in your .babelrc file as well

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"] 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't help. Webpack versions are the same on both (3.5.6).

Comment: Kindly have a look at this link, https://github.com/gokulkrishh/how-to-setup-webpack-2 maybe you are missing something.

Comment: Also in your presets, add es2015 first and then react, because it compiles in that order. have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: For me it wasn't even working locally, I went through Webpack's documentation and saw that they were using require instead of import. What my guess is that webpack compiles all the code to es6 but it doesn't compile the code for itself i.e, webpack.demo.js file etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when I use the free tier. I changed to a 4GB ram and now everything is running.